# Are first-generation college students considered an "underrepresented group" in academia?

Tags: job-search, diversity

Neither of my parents went to college. Is this something that can be brought up in the context of university diversity hiring and outreach?

This is for academic jobs - postdoc, tenure-track, etc.

Comment: What's your country? In many countries, they use college entrance exam to determine who can go to college. For example, about 10 million students take college entrance exam trying to get into college in China every year. So, college education has nothing to do with diversity and outreach in China.

Comment: Is this for undergraduate admissions, graduate admissions, or a job application?

Comment: I expect this would be considered for admission to undergraduate programs.  But not for postdoc, tenure-track, etc.

Comment: I am always a little surprised at the reported number of 'first generation' college students at the California's UC system. It always seems improbably high to me.

Comment: great question. my 1st thought is like no in letter but yes in spirit. my 2nd thought is given that you're 1st gen...perhaps there's another underrepresented group that you belong to? i just came up a theorem in academic applications: 1st gen is necessarily in some underrepresented group (at least for maybe 1950s onwards) !

Answer (score 26):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)-based answer.

Yes, you can mention it, and in theory it can help as it is something that some institutions’ policies, and some individual faculty members, care about. Some caveats to keep in mind:

1. The word “outreach” as used in US academia has no connection to this issue.
2. It would probably matter more in the context of undergraduate/graduate admissions than for academic jobs. However, it might still matter a bit for academic jobs.
3. How you bring this up matters: you can mention it in a “good way” that might slightly help your application, but if you’re not thoughtful about what you write you can also mention it in a “bad way” that will have no effect, or even slightly hurt your application, by showing you to be a person who misunderstands why universities care about this issue and/or who thinks that their first generation college student status makes them entitled to preferential treatment in hiring.
4. Related to but separately from the above, you can bring this up in an “honest way” or a “dishonest way”. Here, by “honest way” I mean bringing this up out of a genuine belief that this information is relevant to the question of whether you deserve to be hired over someone who has similar qualifications to you but has parents who went to college. And “dishonest way” is bringing this up without having that belief, but just knowing that this might help your chances. (The words honest/dishonest are just an approximation; some people might disagree that there’s anything dishonest about the second approach. But just to give an example, if you grew up in a wealthy household with privileged access to many resources that helped you succeed academically, but your parents just happened to have never gone to college, and you mention that latter fact but not the former, I would consider that dishonest and a form of gaming the system. Which is not to say that it wouldn’t work, just that it’s ethically questionable.)

Obviously, it would be best if you bring up the issue in an honest, good way. But you might do it in a dishonest, good way, or in an honest, bad way, or in a dishonest, bad way. I wouldn’t advise you to do it in a bad way, and I wouldn’t advise you to do it in a dishonest way. But avoiding those pitfalls, the answer to your question is “yes, you can mention it”.

Hope this helps, and good luck with your job search!

Comment: (+1) "I wouldn’t advise you to do it in a bad way...".  Ha ha, such helpful advice.  I think I will steal this line as generic advice to students on all matters.

Comment: 'The word “outreach” as used in US academia has no connection to this issue.'  In the UK, the relevant term of art would be "widening participation".

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 3? You describe a "good way" and "bad way," but give no hint as to how to produce (or avoid) either of those effects.

Comment: @DrakeP I’m happy to give general advice that helps OP make sense of some of the bewildering things universities are asking for in job applications these days. But coaching them what to write to achieve specific effects like you are asking about could seriously undermine what universities are trying to achieve with their hiring process — they want to know what job applicants think, not what they’ve been advised to write by someone else. So I don’t feel comfortable offering advice at that level of specificity, sorry.

Comment: @DanRomik alright, I can understand that perspective. Thanks for the consideration

Comment: 1+ for clearly stating US-based.

Comment: Here is one "honest way": you might have been a McNair scholar or at least be interested contributing to the McNair program at that university.  (I was a McNair scholar for 1st gen reasons, and at least at that time and place 90% of the McNair scholars were black.)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, colleges do track and care about encouraging first generation college students.  An undergraduate application might even have a place to indicate status as a first gen.  It's unlikely you'd ever see that on an application for a faculty or post-doc position however.  But you might still work a mention into one of the essays you may be required to submit, perhaps to explain your passion for diversity, that you bring the "I've been there" lived experience of understanding of the challenges first gen and minority students face.

Comment: I'm not sure who you're thinking of with "understanding of the challenges first gen **and minority students** face" reference at the end though? Perhaps just redundantly referring to first gen as a minority status? Because being a first-gen student doesn't really help you understand e.g. the experiences of LGBT students or those of people of color, and it'd be rather naive to suggest otherwise IMO.

Comment: @aquirdturtle "being a first-gen student doesn't really help you understand e.g. the experiences of LGBT students or those of people of color, and it'd be rather naive to suggest otherwise" - further still, people in those groups may take offence at one's suggestion that it would help, as it minimises their experiences (which may include abuse, oppression and persecution) by suggesting that a lack of education would allow you to relate. Such groups are usually implied when the term "diversity" is used, so I would also be careful about my usage of that term in any application.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I'm LGBT and I would not be offended.  I would expect that someone who felt different than other students when they were an UG would have some compassion and understanding of what it feels like to be different.  YMMV.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Being a first-generation student is different from being a "minority student," but, well, the experiences of being an African-American student, an African international student, a Vietnamese-American student, an LGB student, a trans student are all pretty different from each other too. In my application materials, I talked about my experiences as a trans student/academic and tried to relate them to compassion for and some understanding of students with challenges from other groups. I agree with Nicole that a first-gen student writing something on those lines feels very appropriate.

Comment: @Danica Some people may appreciate the similarities between first-generation and typical minority groups for mentioning it to count in one's favour, while others could be offended due to the differences. One could probably express a similar sentiment while avoiding the "diversity" and "minority" terms specifically (or at least being very careful about how one uses those terms), to get the potential benefit of the former without the downside of the latter.

Comment: @NotThatGuy  Is you argument that LGBT and minorities might be offended based on personal experience as an LBGT or minority or is it just speculation?  There's a difference.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton I am a robot and all my arguments about humans are based on observation and analysis. ("based on personal experience as an LBGT or minority" or "just speculation" is a false dichotomy.)

Comment: @NotThatGuy Okay, so have you *observed* that LGBT or minority students are offended if a first gen student remarks that they feel their experience helps explain their passion for diversity and understanding of the challenges first gen and minority students face?  I have not.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton "based on observation *and analysis*", not just "based on observation". If you assert that only experiences that exactly match the one in question matter and any reasoning based on similar and related situations is "just speculation", that would raise some rather concerning questions about the idea of learning and pattern recognition in general, as well as the entire field of psychology. You're again implying a false dichotomy: either I have observed this exact situation, or I'm incapable of having a reasonable justification for how someone would react in such a situation.

Comment: @NotThatGuy  Okay, so you haven't observed anything that supports your claims or your "analysis" and you have nothing else to offer as "reasonable justification" except a word salad.  Good to know.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton So you expect me to summarise here the decades worth of life experience that led me to this belief? Firstly, that seems quite unreasonable to expect anyone to be able to do to any significant degree. Secondly, that is asking a stranger for what they might consider to be quite private details about themselves and their life. Thirdly, my only claim relates to what "some people" might do, which doesn't seem like it should require a high, if any, burden of proof. Lastly, you've been dismissive of me in practically every reply, so why in the world do you think I'd open up to you?

Comment: @NicoleHamilton Had you said, based on your experiences, that people most likely wouldn't take offence, I wouldn't have had any objection. This is pretty much what you did initially, which I didn't object to. But then you felt the need to take it one step further and try to seemingly dismiss my experience completely and assert that I don't have any justification whatsoever to say that even one single person would take offence, which seems like quite an extraordinary claim from your side, that would require extraordinary evidence, not to mention the added burden to dismiss someone's experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130287/discussion-between-nicole-hamilton-and-notthatguy).

Answer (score 9):

I taught for many years at a school where many students were the first in their families to attend college. We were proud of that record.

This fact about your life will be a positive factor in your application, since it suggests motivation that might not be there in an application from a student from a family where college was just "expected". Some schools like mine value it very highly.

That said, I doubt that there is any formal characterization of your status as "diversity" or "outreach".

Answer (score 5):

I think that the earlier answers were focused more on undergraduate education, where there can be some effect in the US.

However, for post PhD position, post docs and regular academic jobs, I doubt that anyone will hire you because you went farther in school than your parents did. The focus will be on you and what you can offer. It will depend on predictions that you will fit a position and the recommendations of others who can support those predictions.

That said, there are people who went to the finest schools because their grandparents and such did and those people get hired, but a lot of that isn't for the quality of the applicant. A lot of that turns out to be misplaced faith.

But, for the great bulk of people, at that age and level of education, it is on you, both your accomplishments and your perceived potential. Other aspects of diversity might count for something in these days but not first-generation alone.

I was one of the first generation folks. My mother had a 2 year nursing degree and I had some uncles with bachelors degrees. I had the support of teachers to get into college and suspect that the family history paid no part. It did help me get scholarships, though. But everything post BA was entirely on me and the recognized (by professors) fact that I knew some things, had some insight, and worked hard. FWIW, I became an academic and my uncles became rich.

---

There are a few colleges, perhaps not especially prestigious, that specialize in first generation students. For jobs at those places you might get an edge for a faculty position if it is perceived that you are more likely to understand the needs of the students.

Comment: I agree that first gen status is likely to be far more relevant for an UG applicant.  For a faculty position, I think it might be helpful if it's connected to the applicant's passion for diversity and the "I've been there" experience they bring.

Comment: In the UK, this year's [annual report](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1003977/State_of_the_nation_2021_-_Social_mobility_and_the_pandemic.pdf) of the Social Mobility Commission recommends that universities start collecting and reporting data on the distribution of socio-economic backgrounds among their staff, to match existing efforts with respect to students.

Answer (score 5):

The literal fact of being first-generation college grad is not quite what "diversity and outreach" can be about, at the level of faculty positions in the U.S., I think.

Namely, I would be interested in the *awareness* of faculty candidates about the difficulties first-gen students face, as well as the difficulties other "traditionally under-represented" demographics face. E.g., college is easier if your parents can tell you what it's like, *and* have the money to allow you to not worry about money too much while you're in school.

Faculty in roles of appraisal of undergrad applicants and grad-program applicants should (in my opinion) be aware that some people have had more opportunities and advantages in early demonstration of talent and interest. That is, peoples' early-life accomplishments certainly occur in the context of their family and social environment. Having been through difficulties oneself *can* lead to better understanding of those difficulties... but, not necessarily.

In particular, at the faculty hiring level, in very legitimate regards it's not literal *membership* in traditionally under-represented groups, but awareness and some understanding that no, "it's not a level playing field".

Comment: Would doing something to support first-generation students count?

Comment: @cgb5436, I'd certainly think so!